# SQL Left Join error - sports app

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble joining a count to my query. I have a table that stores goal events. Each of the columns 'scorer' 'assist1' and 'assist2' hold player ids. I am trying to find the number of times a playerid either appears in the scorer, assist1 or assist2 but ONLY WHEN THE TYPE IS **pp**

```
goalEvents

 gid scorer assist1 assist2 type
  1    1       2       3     eve
  1    1       2      NULL   pp
  1    1       2       3     sh
```

QUERY

```
SELECT 
    p.playerid, p.playernum,
    CONCAT_WS('. ', SUBSTR(p.playerfname, 1, 1), p.playerlname) name,
    COALESCE(pp.powerplay, 0) PPP
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS powerplay FROM goalEvents WHERE scorer = p.playerid OR assist1 = p.playerid OR assist2 = p.playerid AND type='pp'   
) pp 
WHERE p.playerteam = 1
```

What I want as end result

```
id   name  PPP
 1 P. Name  1
 2 A. Name  1
 3 S. Name  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the LEFT JOIN clause and add a SUB SELECT in your returning columns. Also mind the parenthesis to separate the OR's from the AND. Try something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT 
    playerid, 
    playernum,
    CONCAT_WS('. ', SUBSTR(playerfname, 1, 1), playerlname) name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS powerplay FROM goalEvents 
     WHERE (scorer = playerid OR assist1 = playerid OR assist2 = playerid) 
     AND type='pp') AS PPP
FROM players
WHERE playerteam = 1
```